# Javascript function

Tags: javascript

> TASK: Complete the solution so that it returns true if the first argument(string) passed in ends with the 2nd argument (also a string).

MY SOLUTION:

```js
function solution(str, ending) {
  if (str.slice(-1) === ending.slice(-1)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(
  solution('sumo', 'omo') // returned false!!!
)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It returns true but that is because you compare `o` to `o`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: To make it work using your idea of slicing you can simply use the `ending.length`. So it would be `if (str.slice(-ending.length) === ending) {` (keep in mind if `ending.length > str.length` you can return false immediately.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.prototype.endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).

```js
function solution(str1, str2) {
  return str1.endsWith(str2);
}

console.log(solution("football", "ball")); // true
console.log(solution("football", "foot")); // false
console.log(solution("football", "oot")); // false
```

If you want the comparison to be **case insensitive**, then you can compare the [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) version of both the strings.

```js
function solution(str1, str2) {
  return str1.toLowerCase().endsWith(str2.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(solution("FOOTBALL", "ball")); // true
console.log(solution("footBall", "BALL")); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
function solution(str, ending) {
  if (str.includes(ending)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(solution("football", "ball")); // true
console.log(solution("football", "foot")); // true
console.log(solution("sumo", "um")); // true
```

Comment: Think? Why not make a `[<>]` snippet and show it works?
You have the test the wrong way around. You want str to include ending.
It still actually does not since includes is anywhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

A more modern version (ES6+) of the function declaration would be this oneliner

```
const solution = (str1, str2) => str1.endsWith(str2);
```

If you need case insensitive testing. you can also construct a regular expression so you do not need to lowerCase.

Remove the `"i"` to leave it case sensitive

```js
const solution = (str1, str2) => new RegExp(str2+"$","i").test(str1);

console.log(solution("football", "ball")); // true
console.log(solution("football", "Ball")); // true
console.log(solution("football", "foot")); // false
console.log(solution("sumo", "um")); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function lastMatch(str, ending) {
  if (str.endsWith(ending)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(lastMatch("football", "l"));
console.log(lastMatch("football", "foot"));
console.log(lastMatch("football", "all"));
```